# Asynchronous I/O (reading stream from asynchronous webrequest)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm running into a bit of problem when trying to post data asynchronously. Here's the code:

```
    public string PostHTTP(string http, string data)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http);
        postData = data;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        allDone.WaitOne();
        Referer = http;
        return information;
    }

    private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult); //Here is problem
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
        postStream.Close();
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse' to type 'System.Exception'.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you paste the exception esp. the stack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asynchronous I/O (Reading stream from async webrequest)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114568/asynchronous-i-o-reading-stream-from-async-webrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx).  Try calling `EndGetResponse` on your request object instead of `EndGetRequestStream`.  Then, if that executes successfully, you can call `GetResponseStream`.

Comment: I swear i'm horrible at attention to detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `PostHTTP()` method, you called `BeginGetResponse()` yet in the callback you use `EndGetRequestStream()`.  These are completely different operations.  Shouldn't you be using `EndGetResponse()`?  Or at least start off with `BeginGetRequest()`?